# How to retrieve List by a Consumer with Spring and rabbitmq

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-8, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have two projects

1. WebApp(SpringMVC)
2. Microservice

The idea is that I have a page in which I list all the users from DB, so basically I need a listener on WebApp side and a producer in the microservice side, typically the flow is as follow

**Whitout rabbitmq(synchronous)**

1. Click page "List Users"
2. UserController that redirect me to a specific service

   ```
   public List<User>getUsers(){//no args!!
      service.getUsers();//no args
   }
   ```
3. UserService with logic to access DB and retrieve all users

   ```
   public List<User>getUsers(){//no args!!
      //connect to DB and retrieve all users
      return users
   }
   ```
4. Render users on jsp

**With RabbitMQ and assuming users has already been produced the list of users on the microservice's side**

My question is about if I introduce rabbitmq then I need a method in which I listen a message(List of products as a JSON) but now the flow change a little bit comparing with the first one because

1. Click button "List Users"
2. Controller need a method findAll(Message message), here I  need pass a message because the service is expecting one as the  service is  Listener

   ```
   public List<User>getUsers(Message message){
       service.getAllUsers(**String message**);
   }
   ```
3. The service as right now is listen a message, I need to pass a Message 
   arg in which I will be listen the queues

   ```
   @RabbitListener(queues = "${queue}", containerFactory = "fac")
   public List<User> getUsers(String message){
        //Transform JSON to POJO 
        //some logic...
        return users;

   }
   ```

   So basically my question is the second flow is correct?

   If so how I have to pass the Message object from controller to service 
   because in controller I do not needed a Message, but in order to 
   listen I have, is this correct?

   If so how pass the message arg

   There is a better way to achieve this?

   Regards

Comment: your flow is not correct. in 1st scenario you have 1 microservice with controller-service-database. in 2nd scenario (if you're putting a message queue in the middle) you decouple the logic between 2 components+queue. So you have 1 microservice that PRODUCES messages to rabbit, and a separate microservice that CONSUMES messages from the rabbit. and you don't need controller for your CONSUMER-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` and the framework will do all the conversion for you.

Controller:

```
List<User> users = template.convertSendAndReceiveAsType("someExchange", "someRoutingKey", 
    myRequestPojo, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<User>>() {});
```

Server:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${queue}", containerFactory = "fac")
public List<User> getUsers(SomeRequestPojo request){
     //some logic...
     return users;
}
```

Wire the converter into both the listener container factory and the `RabbitTemplate`.

Request Pojo and Users have to be Jackson-friendly (no-arg constructor, setters).